# tcpdump filter does not work, why?

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump

I have a machine which has a port connected to a monitor port on a switch. Thus, many packets from different sources and destinations are arriving at its interface. However, I cannot seem to filter based on certain IP addresses.

For example, I try to do this, but I see no traffic:

```
# tcpdump -n -nn -i p2p2 host 239.31.80.152  
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on p2p2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

But if I do a simple grep, I can see packets come in:

```
# tcpdump -n -nn -i p2p2 | grep 239.31.80.152
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on p2p2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
20:32:26.535506 IP 10.232.4.7.41724 > 239.31.80.152.10502: UDP, length 38
20:32:26.635546 IP 10.232.4.7.41724 > 239.31.80.152.10502: UDP, length 38
```

If I dump the packets to a pcap file, I cannot filter based on that host, either.

But I can filter on another host or network as I wish:

```
# tcpdump -n -nn -i p2p2 src net 50
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on p2p2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
21:01:05.104011 IP 50.93.139.140.60745 > 233.90.130.137.13090: UDP, length 20
21:01:05.140072 IP 50.93.139.140.60745 > 233.90.130.137.13090: UDP, length 75

# tcpdump -n -nn -i p2p2 dst host 233.90.130.137
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on p2p2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
21:01:17.940104 IP 50.93.139.140.60745 > 233.90.130.137.13090: UDP, length 460
21:01:17.954007 IP 50.93.139.140.60745 > 233.90.130.137.13090: UDP, length 20
21:01:18.000084 IP 50.93.139.140.60745 > 233.90.130.137.13090: UDP, length 59
```

What is peculiar about that host 239.31.80.152?

Comment: Probably has something to do with it being a multicast IP.

Comment: Somewhat related: [sometimes you need to specify](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/misadventures-with-tcpdump-filters/) `vlan and host 1.1.1.1`

Comment: @MichaelHampton both of the examples I've shown are multicast IPs. I can filter 233.90.130.137 just fine. Regardless, the question remains: It certainly has something to do with another thing, but what is the something? Furthermore, what is the another thing?

Comment: Augh!!!! Thanks @kubanczyk. What's crazy is I can't find any mention of "vlan" in the tcpdump man page (I know, right? "RTFM" he said, "RTFM"). Anyway, putting `vlan and <rest of filter>` did the trick.